# Express js delegate http verbs

Tags: javascript, express

I have set up a breakpoint on the following line inside an express app.

```
app.get('/api/post/:id', api.post);
```

When I step into the function it goes to:

```
/**
 * Delegate `.VERB(...)` calls to `.route(VERB, ...)`.
 */

methods.forEach(function(method){
  app[method] = function(path){
    if (1 == arguments.length) return this.routes.lookup(method, path);
    var args = [method].concat(toArray(arguments));
    if (!this.__usedRouter) this.use(this.router);
    return this.routes._route.apply(this.routes, args);
  }
});
```

Can anyone explain what is happening? How and why was it directed to this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted bit of code is the contents declaration of the `app.get` function.

`methods` will be an array of verbs (`get`, `post`, `put`, etc), and each is declared as a function on `app`.

I assume what you're actually interested in is the `api.post` function. To inspect that you'll have to put a breakpoint in that function, or step into the `apply` on this line `this.routes._route.apply(this.routes, args);` to see what happens next.

Comment: no i was interested in the get function, i was expecting to be taken to the definition of the get method but got the above instead.

Comment: @Paul43 That is the definition of the `get` method :) It's defined in the same way as all the other verbs. The above function applies the arguments that are passed to the function, adds the verb `get` then calls `this.routes._route` with them.